# Using printf in awk

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I have two files $A and $B

$A contains (the operator varies, it could be =, > or !=) Basically I have the awk command working as it should I just want to add the line from $A where it failed

```
number1 = 460
number2 = 12
number3 > 5
number4 > 20
number5 != 39
number6 != 0
```

$B contains

```
number1 453
number2 12
number3 7
number4 19
number5 39
number6 4
```

I have an awk command that compares two files and tells me if the numbers don't match

```
output=`awk '
   {
       getline buf <f2;
       split( buf, a, " " );

       if( $1 == a[1]  && $2 == ">" && $3+0 > a[2]+0 )
           printf( "%s\n", buf );
       else if( $1 == a[1]  && $2 == "!=" && $3+0 == a[2]+0 )
           printf( "%s\n", buf );
       else if( $1 == a[1]  && $2 == "=" && $3+0 != a[2]+0 )
           printf( "%s\n", buf );

   }
' f2="$B" $A`

echo "$output"
number1 453
number4 19
number5 39
```

I am trying to get this output:

```
echo "$output"
This is the line that failed: number1 = 460 #coming from $A
This is the correct number: number1 453 #coming from $B

This is the line that failed: number4 > 20 #coming from $A
This is the correct number: number4 19 #coming from $B

This is the line that failed: number5 != 39 #coming from $A
This is the correct number: number5 39 #coming from $B
```

Comment: awk is a separate programming language, not part of bash. And bash has a printf but it's completely separate from awk's printf. There's a lot that could be done to make this clearer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks I'll edit the title

Comment: BTW, `echo $output` is itself inherently buggy (of particular note it'll eat your newlines and print all your output on the same line, even when you've gotten your code fixed to the point where awk is writing two separate lines of output); _always_ `echo "$output"` instead -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy agreed. I fixed it

Comment: And `awk` can easily do that in single command without any `bash` directive

Comment: @j1-lee Thanks for your input. I edited the question with more examples of operators. Hopefully its makes it better to understand

Comment: If you're ever considering using `getline` in future, by the way, then make sure to read http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline to understand the very few cases where using `getline` is appropriate and how to code it correctly to avoid the various associated issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    map[$1] = $2+0
    next
}
$1 in map {
    succ = 0
    if (    ( ($2 == "=" ) && (map[$1] == $3) ) \
         || ( ($2 == "!=") && (map[$1] != $3) ) \
         || ( ($2 == ">" ) && (map[$1] >  $3) ) \
         || ( ($2 == ">=") && (map[$1] >= $3) ) \
         || ( ($2 == "<" ) && (map[$1] <  $3) ) \
         || ( ($2 == "<=") && (map[$1] <= $3) ) \
       ) {
        succ = 1
    }
    if ( !succ ) {
        printf "This is the line that failed: %s #coming from %s\n", $0, FILENAME
        printf "This is the correct number: %s %s #coming from %s\n", $1, map[$1], ARGV[1]
        print ""
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk B A
This is the line that failed: number1 = 460 #coming from A
This is the correct number: number1 453 #coming from B

This is the line that failed: number4 > 20 #coming from A
This is the correct number: number4 19 #coming from B

This is the line that failed: number5 != 39 #coming from A
This is the correct number: number5 39 #coming from B
```

Comment: this works great. I was able to fit this inside my bash script. Thanks for your help

Comment: instead of $2 == "=" how can I call anything between 2 commas instead of $2 column

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means (I can imagine several things it **might** mean) and [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged anyway so please just ask a  new followup question.

Answer (score 0):

As I prefer to use `sed` over `awk`, there is something:

```
diff -y file1 file2 |
    sed 's/^\(.*\) = *\([0-9]\+\)[ \o11]\+|[ \o11]\+\1/\1 :: \2 !/p;d'
number1 :: 460 ! = 453
```

You could arrange:

```
diff -y file? |
    sed 's/^\(.*\) = *\([0-9]\+\)[ \o11]\+|[ \o11]\+\1 = *\([0-9]\+\)/This is the line that failed: \1 = \2 # coming from file1\nThis is the correct number: \1 = \3 # comming from file2/p;d'
This is the line that failed: number1 = 460 # coming from file1
This is the correct number: number1 = 453 # comming from file2
```

Comment: Thank you for the sed option however in my case I will have different operators. file1 might have != while file 2 might have >. You can see the criteria in the awk command